# How to connect to sql server with impersonation?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, impersonation

Our sql server connection policy just changed. I have been informed that the user name and password provided have now the following format:

> user name: {domain-name}{user-name}
>
> password: {password}

I have also been told that only impersonated user can log into the server with the connection string having above user name and password.

I tried with the regular SqlConnection but got "Login failed for '{domain-name}{user-name}'. I am working with sql server 2012.

What should I do to implement that 'impersonation' stuff?

Comment: What does your connection string look like? Were you using SQL authentication before?

Comment: Your .Net code needs to be running as the domain user and your connection string needs to use Integrated Security=SSPI;

Comment: @TaylorN, yes, my connection string still contains user id and password. Rhys Jones, now I removed user id and password from connection string, and added Integrated Security = true. Now it works. Thank you both.

Comment: Now, though it works when I create impersonation right before opening connection to sql server, it is tedious since I have to this before opening connection each time. I tried with a closure. But it is failing each time. Any idea on creating impersonation once (in a class) and reuse it each time?